# How to use Binance API, simple GET price by ticker

Tags: java, binance

I would like to get only one pair from the response. And I can't really understand how I should pass my parameter.

Instructions say:

> Symbol price ticker
> GET `/api/v3/ticker/price`
> Latest price for a symbol or symbols.
> Weight: 1 for a single symbol; 2 when the symbol parameter is omitted
> Parameters:
> Name  Type    Mandatory   Description
> symbol    STRING  NO  -
> If the symbol is not sent, prices for all symbols will be returned in an array."

I'm able to get all symbols in the response body, but can't get a single one.
I have already tried (in Postman) these endpoints:

1. `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price/btcusdt`
2. `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price/symbol=btcusdt`
3. `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price/?symbol=btcusdt`

Here is the link to entire API:
`https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#24hr-ticker-price-change-statistics`

So, which endpoint is correct?

[image: postman result]

Comment: Check here `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price` to see what acceptable symbols you can choose from. Then you use this `https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC` to, for example, get the single pair for LTCBTC. Let me know if this answers your question, or if you need more clarification.

Comment: Yes, now I see my mistakes. Redundant slash ('/') after "price" and lowerCase symbol. Thank You for Your answer.

Answer (score 36):

3. `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price/?symbol=btcusdt`

You must use Query without `/`

and Binance's /api/v3/ticker/price endpoint need symbol query as `Upper case`.

so you must request as below

`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT`

Comment: how to fetch with specific date or date time i have searched with 
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCUSDT
but i want to fetch with etc.
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/1274123617?symbol=BTCUSDT
in above url after ticker the number is unix date time. but unfortunately i can't get response.

Answer (score 13):

You can you this API link to get all pairs only current price and symbols:

```
https://www.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price
```

This for specific symbol and price:

```
https://www.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BNBBTC
```

This for all pairs with full info:

```
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo
```

This for 1 pair full info:

```
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo?symbol=BNBBTC
```

Here is Binance API Detail pages:

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en

https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

Comment: how to fetch with specific date or date time i have searched with api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCUSDT but i want to fetch with etc. api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/1274123617?symbol=BTCUSDT in url after ticker the number is unix date time. but unfortunately i can't get response.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a chance to send more queries at once like for example
BTCUSDT and ETHUSDT ?

When I am trying various combinations I get a reply of:

```
{"code":-1104,"msg":"Not all sent parameters were read; read '1' parameter(s) but was sent '2'."}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31668339)

Comment: `?symbols=["BNBBTC","ETHUSDT"]`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can send multiple symbols but you have to loop

```
for (const symbol of symbols) {
const query_String = await queryString({ symbol });
 await axios({
  method: "GET",
  url: `${Settings.Endpoint}/v3/ticker/price?${query_String}`,
})
```

}